# R turn irregular time interval into regular ones using previous numbers

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, zoo

i have an irregular time interval like this

```
df=data.frame(Date=c("2013-01-08","2013-01-11","2013-01-13","2013-01-21","2013-02-06"), runningtotal=c(800,910,1060,1210,660)
```

i found through zoo object it can be merged with a regular time interval and fill in 0 as missing values. However, I need to fill in previous value instead, except at month start fill it with 0. So the end output is like this:

```
date       runningtotal
2013-01-01 0
2013-01-02 0
...
2013-01-08 800
2013-01-09 800
2013-01-10 800
2013-01-11 910
2013-01-12 910
2013-01-13 1060
...
2013-02-01 0
```

And also, does it make sense to fill in value like this for forecasting purpose?

Thanks.

Comment: Use `na.locf`? (I would do a rolling join with data.tables.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `approxfun` with the `constant` method. I don't have `lubridate` and just deal with regular `Date` objects. For instance:

```
  df<-data.frame(Date=c("2013-01-08","2013-01-11","2013-01-13","2013-01-21","2013-02-06"), runningtotal=c(800,910,1060,1210,660))
  df$Date<-as.Date(as.character(df$Date))
  #create some new dates
  newDates<-seq(df$Date[1],df$Date[5],length.out=10)  
  intfun<-approxfun(df$Date,df$runningtotal,method="constant",yleft=0,yright=0)
  data.frame(newDates,intfun(newDates))
```

Comment: I don't understand in what this answer the question? the expected output is different from the final result. The answer is accepted so surely I miss something.

Comment: Yes, I agree that the answer missed the point to give a 0 to the first days of a month. Nonetheless, I think the use of `approxfun` may have been helpful. Of course if OP wants to "disaccept" my answer (is that even possible?) I've no problem with it.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `na.locf` from `zoo` package. But You should prepare data before applying it.

```
## generate a vector of dates  
mm <- min(DF$Date)
day(mm) <- 1
seq_dates <- seq.POSIXt(mm,max(DF$Date),by='days')
## add zeros valus for the beging of month
DF <- rbind(DF,data.frame(Date=seq_dates[day(seq_dates)==1],runningtotal=0))
library(zoo)
## merge with the sequence of dates , and apply na.locf for previous values.
na.locf(merge(seq_dates,DF,by=1,all.x=TRUE))
```

The idea is to apply `na.locf` that change missing values with the previous non missing values. Merge your data with a sequence of dates(from the first month to the end of dates) will insert missing values.

Comment: Could also be done like this: `library(zoo); z <- read.zoo(df); g <- seq(start(z), end(z), "day"); zz <- na.locf(merge(zoo(, g), z))`.  At this point `coredata(zz)` and `time(zz)` are the data and dates.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck well but you still have to deal with : 1- the 0 at the beginning of months.and 2- create the `g` from the the first date of the first month.

Comment: Didn't notice that.  Change it to: `z <- read.zoo(df); g <- seq(as.Date(as.yearmon(start(z))), end(z), "day");
na.fill(na.locf(merge(zoo(, g), z), na.rm = FALSE), 0)`